# Jquery Scroll to Bottom of DIV Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a simple chat box in jquery that scrolls to the bottom when the page loads. I have seen lots of different methods for this (most of which have done nothing)

This method here animates a scroll down, but it appears to only do it this height of the div. So, after the page is loaded.. It's srolled about a 5th of the way down the div.

Here is my code.
Any help would be appreciated

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    //Load Previous Chat Messages
    $("#messages").load('/ajax-request?parse=true');


    THIS ONLY SCROLLS A LITTLE BIT
    $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);

    $("#userArea").submit(function() {

        $.post('/ajax-post?parse=true', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data) {
            //Append the Newest Post onto the Chat
            $("#messages").append(data);
            //Clear the Input Box
            $('#textBody').val('');
            //Scroll the chat to the bottom when new chat is posted

            THIS ONE WORKS JUST FINE
            $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight);

        });

        return false;
    });
});

</script>




<!-- Display -->
<div id="messages" style="overflow:auto;height:150px;width:350px;" >
</div>

<!-- Post -->
<form id="userArea">
    <!-- Message -->
    <input id="textBody" type="text" maxlength="255" name="messages" autocomplete="off"/>
    <!--Submit-->
    <input type="submit" value="Post Message" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the animate inside the load callback function, like so:

```
//Load Previous Chat Messages
$("#messages").load('/ajax-request?parse=true', function(){
    // This should fire once the request is fully loaded
    $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/B8aGv/

```
 $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#messages").position().top }, 1000);
```